# Vim, How make vmap shortcut running once?

Tags: vim

Hello I have vimconfig (test.vim):

```
set nocompatible
vmap t :call Hello()<cr>

fun! Hello() "{{{
    echom "I work with selection"
endfunction "}}}
```

I run vim with the configuration, for disable any other settings and plugins:

```
vim -u test.vim test.vim
```

Ok, when I select several lines and press "t", function Hello run **several times**. I would like to make shortcut for visual mode which run only once when key pressed. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want you have two options:

1. Use `function Hello() range` declaration (note the last word). This way you tell vim your function is handling range on its own (otherwise it is assumed to operate on one line, effectively making vim repeat its call for each line in a range). This way range is available via `a:firstline` and `a:lastline`, but you still have to use `'<` and `'>` marks with `col()` function if you want to get columns.
2. Use `<C-u>` right after `:` to clear the range. When you press `:` in visual mode it starts command mode with range (`'<,'>`) already inserted. This range stands for the first and last line in selection. This way selected range is still available, via `'<` and `'>` marks (use `col()`, `line()` or `getpos()` to get actual numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Find answer in Vim Help:

```
:help a:firstline
```

> When the [range] argument is added, the function is expected to take care of a range itself. 
>   The range is          passed as "a:firstline" and "a:lastline".  If [range]
>             is excluded, ":{range}call" will call the function for          each line
>   in the range, with the cursor on the start            of each line.  See
>   |function-range-example|.             The cursor is still moved to the first
>   line of the           range, as is the case with all Ex commands.

So function Hello should be defined like:

```
fun Hello() range
    echom "I work with selection"
end
```